# How to find a string in a variable using PHP and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find the word and add a number next to it. How could he do? I tried with the code below, but I could not. Could anyone help me?
Thank you!

```
$string = 'I220ABCD I220ABCDEF I220ABCDEFG'
if (preg_match("/I220.*/", $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Expected result:
I220ABCD9
I220ABCDEF10
I220ABCDEFG11

Comment: Wouldn't explode() be enough for this little job ?

Comment: what is the criteria of adding a number? Just add any random number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what your requirnments for adding the number at the end are so i just incremeneted during the loop;

```
$string = 'I220ABCD I220ABCDEF I220ABCDEFG';

$arrayStrings = explode(" ", $string);
$int = 9;
$newString = '';

foreach($arrayStrings as $stringItem)
{   
    if (preg_match("/I220.*/", $stringItem, $matches)) 
    {

        $stringItem = $stringItem.$int;
        $newString = $newString.$stringItem." ";
        $int++;
    }
}

echo $newString;
```

Comment: Thank you, I could adapt to my system perfectly!

Comment: You very welcome, dont forget to mark a question as answered by selecting the checkmark next to the applicable post so future users can benefit from your question

Comment: if my string was so, how would I do to get a code I220?  $string = '**I220AB FRRRR CD** I221ABCDEF **I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG**';

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead like this:

```
$str = 'I220AB FRRRR CD I221ABCDEF I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG';
$repl= preg_replace_callback('~(I220[^\s]+)~', function($m) {
         static $i=9;
         return $m[1] . $i++;
       }, $str);

echo $repl\n"; // I220AB9 FRRRR CD I221ABCDEF I220AB10 DSFDSF CDEFG
```

Comment: Thanks! But as I pass one by one?

Comment: if my string was so, how would I do to get a code I220? $string = '**I220AB FRRRR CD** I221ABCDEF **I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG**';

Comment: My desired output: I220AB FRRRR CD and I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG

Comment: You question starts with: `I am trying to find the word and add a number next to it.` And in your desired output I don't see any number being added.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a catch block in your regex e.g. `"/I220([^ ]+)/"` and if you want them all, you'll need to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), too.

Comment: Thank you! But as I pass one by one?

Comment: You can just put it in a loop: `foreach($matches as $match) { print_r($match); }`

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = 'I220ABCD I220ABCDEF I220ABCDEFG';
// This requires PHP5.3+ since it's using an anonymous function
$result = preg_replace_callback('/I220[^\s]*/', function($match){
    return($match[0].rand(0,10000)); // Add a random number between 0-10000
}, $string);

echo $result; // I220ABCD3863 I220ABCDEF5640 I220ABCDEFG989
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gd510a).

Comment: I'm answering your question with a solution.

Comment: if my string was so, how would I do to get a code I220? $string = '**I220AB FRRRR CD** I221ABCDEF **I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG**';

Comment: @user1997072 What's the desired output ?

Comment: I220AB FRRRR CD and I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG

Comment: @user1997072 that's the input, I'm talking about the output, you want to add a number right ?

Comment: too, but would like to return the complete record of each I220

Comment: each record I220: I220AB FRRRR CD and I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG

Comment: @user1997072 ~Sigh~ ... Really tiresome, you asked a question and I answered it, and now you're coming with a different problem, so why didn't you come with this in the beginning ? Moreover what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace_callback with your needs:

```
    $string = 'I220ABCD I220ABCDEF I220ABCDEFG';


   class MyClass{

       private static $i = 9;

       private static function callback($matches){
           return $matches[0] . self::$i++;
       }

       public static function replaceString($string){
            return preg_replace_callback('/I220[^\s]+/',"self::callback",$string);  
       }
   }


   echo(MyClass::replaceString($string));
```

of course you can edit to class to initialize the way you want

Comment: if my string was so, how would I do to get a code I220? $string = '**I220AB FRRRR CD** I221ABCDEF **I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG**';

Comment: My desired output: I220AB FRRRR CD and I220AB DSFDSF CDEFG